# Accessing array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array

```
var user = [{
        id: '541231',
        name: 'mitsos',
        serialNumber: '12345',
        commonName: 'mitsos',
        email: 'fsfdsa@fdaf.gr',
        telephone: '11223344',
        createdDate: '31/08/1988',
        management: 'DPLR',
        hierarchy: 'ergatis'
    }];
$scope.adata = [];
$scope.adata.push(user);
```

I want display the data from this data. I use `{{ adata.user.name }}` but it does not show anything(also it doesn't display any error), if i use `ng-repeat` it works but by default it will has only one row

Comment: you haev an array of object here, not an object ... you must access it in a loop or by index adata[0][0].name ...

Answer (score 0):

`adata.user.name` shouldn't show anything. `adata` is an array. The value you pushed into it is another array. There is no object with a property called `user` at all.

```
adata[0][0].name
```

Comment: can i insert any filter like json:user or json:name?

Answer (score 0):

You are pushing an array inside an array, with .adata.push(user), and user is an array as well.

So on your ngRepeat, the a simple ng-repeat="user in adata" would result in user being an array, and you would have to access with user[0].

Remove the [] from the user object, and just let it has a simple object.

```
var user = {
    id: '541231',
    name: 'mitsos',
    serialNumber: '12345',
    commonName: 'mitsos',
    email: 'fsfdsa@fdaf.gr',
    telephone: '11223344',
    createdDate: '31/08/1988',
    management: 'DPLR',
    hierarchy: 'ergatis'
};
$scope.adata = [];
$scope.adata.push(user);
```

Also, if you would like to rather access a user list, than what you problably want is:

```
$scope.adata.users = [];
$scope.adata.users.push(user);
```

And then for example:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in adata.users">
  <span ng-bind="user.name"></span>
</div>
```